# polyfill not working on IE11

Tags: javascript, promise, internet-explorer-11, fetch, polyfills

I have created objects with fetch and I am trying to make it work on IE11 with polyfill but it is not working. I have tried to use https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill https://github.com/github/fetch

In my head I have

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="/assets/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="/assets/fetch/fetch.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.min.js"></script>
```

The JavaScript code

```
//To add to window
if (!window.Promise) {
  window.Promise = Promise;
}
const CommsMatrix = {
        getCMDStatuses: function(){
        return fetch('/api/user/list/comms/matrix/data/format/json'+'?csrf='+$.csrfParam('csrf')+'&select=distinct(status)&orderby=status', {
          // body: new URLSearchParams({ csrf: $.csrfParam('csrf'), select:
            // 'distinct(status)', orderby: 'status' })
            credentials: 'include'
        })
        .then(response => {
          return response.headers.error ? Promise.reject(response.headers.error) : response.json();
        }).then(body => {
          return body.body.recordset.record.map(v => v.STATUS)
        })
      },
      getSupportedProtocols: function(){
        return fetch('/api/user/list/sys/list/protocols/format/json'+'?csrf='+$.csrfParam('csrf')+'&orderby=name', {
          // body: new URLSearchParams({ csrf: $.csrfParam('csrf'), orderby:
            // 'name' })
            credentials: 'include'
        })
        .then(response => {
          return response.headers.error ? Promise.reject(response.headers.error) : response.json();
        }).then(body => {
          return body.body.recordset.record.map(v => v.NAME)
        })
      }
}

Promise.all([CommsMatrix.getCMDStatuses(), CommsMatrix.getSupportedProtocols()])
    // Destructuring the 2-item array into statuses and protocols variables
    .then(([ statuses, protocols ]) => {
        // You've got statuses and protocols loaded
        selectField = HTMLFormTag.createSelect(statuses, true, false, 'To implement');
        selectField.setAttribute("name", 'status['+counter+']');
        selectField = selectField.outerHTML;

        selectProtocolField = HTMLFormTag.createSelect(protocols, true, false, 'TCP');
        selectProtocolField.setAttribute("name", 'protocol['+counter+']');
        selectProtocolField = selectProtocolField.outerHTML;

        // Automatically add a first row of data
        $('#addRow').click();
    });
```

In IE11 it complains in 3 places. syntax error on `.then(response => {` and `.then(([ statuses, protocols ]) => {` and `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'csrfParam'`

Comment: You can't use [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with IE

Comment: so how do I rewrite this to work?

Comment: Don't use arrow functions, switch to the old way `function (response) {...}`, or use a transpiller which will translate your code from ES6 to supported javascript version.

Comment: I have changed `response =>` to `function(response)` but I am not sure how to change `([ statuses, protocols ]) =>` and `return body.body.recordset.record.map(v => v.STATUS)`